# Configuring aurelia cli to serve app-bundle from a subfolder

Tags: aurelia

How can I configure aurelia cli to allow the app to be loaded from a subfolder (a mvc controller vith a view)?

In  `/MyController/MyView` I have the following code

```
<div aurelia-app="main" data-module="app2">
     <script src="/scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
</div>
```

I got an 404 when the loader then tries to load the app-bundle from `/MyController/MyView/scripts/app-bundle.js` but it actual location is `/scripts/app-bundle.js`

Thanks for any help

Larsi

*Motivation for question:
I'm using Aurelia in an existing asp.net mvc 5 website. We plan to develop new pages as small aurelia apps (one aurelia app per mvc view). We plan on reusing the same bundles on all views (just setting "aurelia.setRoot('nameofapp')" to launch the correct app). This seems to work great when launching at '/' but when lanched from '/MyController/MyView' we need to modify the location the app-bundles are loaded from - and this is what this question is about.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things needed to be done:

- Set the ´build.targets.baseUrl: '../scripts'´ in ´aurelia.json´
- Use "features" as Matthew suggested.

I figured someone else might need this setup, so I created a repository here: https://github.com/larserikfinholt/aurelia-subfolder

Larsi

Comment: @Larsi I checked out your repo, thanks. How did you know to add the `data-feature=""` attribute? I can't find that documented anywhere.

Comment: @pholly The 'data-feature' name can be any name you choose. You just need to use the same name in main.js

Comment: @Larsi Thanks. I'm mainly asking where did you find the documentation for that attribute. It seems pretty important because without it you wouldn't be able to declare the starting point of the app. I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: @Larsi I see - you just used `data-feature` as a plain data attribute on the element and in the main.js file you grabbed the attribute using jQuery. I thought it was part of the aurelia framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Use "features"

In your `main.js` aurelia bootstrap file, you can write this:

**main.js**

```
configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('my-app');
}
```

This will instruct aurelia to load `my-app/index.js` as a plugin, exposing the `aurelia` object to a `configure()` function, just like in the `main.js` file. You can do all kinds of fun stuff there, including setting a root view model.

**my-app/index.js**

```
configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('my-app/app.js'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the "feature" direction. I needed to do one more step, so I created answer describing my approach.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Is there a way to create two seperate apps, In this case I can see that everything is getting bundled into app-bundle.js. I want two parallel apps serving the different context.